# Where is the Shabbat desecration in the following excerpt from "Ethics from Sinai"?

Tags: shabbat, commentaries, masechet-yoma

In ["Ethics from Sinai"](https://www.feldheim.com/ethics-from-sinai-a-wide-ranging-commentary-on-pirkei-avos-1), his brilliant, three-volume treatise on *Pirkei Avot*, Reb Irving M. Bunim Z”TL writes the following in his commentary to Perek VI, Mishnah 7:

> “So the Talmud tells how Shemayah and Avtaylon found Hillel one
> Sabbath morning atop the skylight of their *beis midrash*, covered by
> over five feet of snow. They removed the snow, brought him down to the
> fire, warmed him and restored his health and spirit. Had his life not
> been at stake, their actions would thus have been a dreadful violation
> of the Sabbath.”

The footnote for this passage indicates that the source of it is [Yoma 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.35b.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

I am at a loss to see what would be the desecration of Shabbat had this not have been a matter of *pikuach nefesh*. Obviously if Shemayah and Avtaylon and/or others had made a fire to warm Hillel, it would be a clear Shabbat violation. But the passage does not indicate that. Indeed, it seems to imply that the fire was already burning.

Perhaps Reb Bunim extracted only a portion of this incident from [Yoma 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.35b.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). But there exists more at that source which reveals the “dreadful violation” that he cites.

I would be very grateful for any insight on this issue. Am I missing something in the words of Reb Bunim? If so, what is the Shabbat violation? Or is there additional language at *Yoma* 35b that shows the Shabbat desecration?

MANY THANKS for any assistance.
(posting from Israel)

Comment: I always assumed they lit a fire

Comment: According to the Ben Yehoyada (by author of Ben Ish Chai) there was no biblical violation of Shabbos, just the Rabbinic ordinance against bathing and annointing.

Comment: That is most interesting. Thank you very much for your post and your time.

Comment: Can it be that one of the violations was removing snow? https://outorah.org/p/47706/

Answer (score 1):

As N.T. posted earlier:

> According to the Ben Yehoyada (by author of Ben Ish Chai) there was no
> biblical violation of Shabbos, just the Rabbinic ordinance against
> bathing and annointing.

The violations do appear to be bathing and anointing. In a Mi Yodeya question from three months ago entitled ["Questions on a story about Hillel"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128149/27180), the following is included:

> *Hillel the Elder worked every day to earn half a dinar, half of which he would give [as tuition] at the study hall… One time he did not find
> employment… and the guard did not let him enter. He went up to the
> roof, and sat at the edge of the skylight to hear the words of the
> living God from the mouths of [Rabbis] Shemaya and Avtalyon. It was
> Shabbat eve … Snow fell upon him from the sky… Shemaya and Avtalyon
> [noticed that less light was entering the study hall], went up, and
> found him covered with snow three cubits high. They freed him, washed
> him and smeared oil on him, and sat him opposite the bonfire to warm
> him. They said: This man is worthy for us to desecrate Shabbat for
> him.* [Yoma 35b]